# Django - Query count of each distinct status

Tags: django, postgresql, django-queryset, django-orm, django-aggregation

I have a model `Model` that has `Model.status` field. The `status` field can be of value `draft`, `active` or `cancelled`.

Is it possible to get a count of all objects based on their status? I would prefer to do that in one query instead of this:

```
Model.objects.filter(status='draft').count()
Model.objects.filter(status='active').count()
Model.objects.filter(status='cancelled').count()
```

I think that `aggregate` could help.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you can work with:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Model.objects.values('status').annotate(
    count=Count('pk')
).order_by('count')
```

This will return a `QuerSet` of dictionaries:

```
<QuerySet [
    {'status': 'active', 'count': 25 },
    {'status': 'cancelled', 'count': 14 },
    {'status': 'draft', 'count': 13 }
]>
```

This will however *not* list statuses for which no `Model` is present in the database.

Or you can make use of an aggregate with `filter=`:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q

Model.objects.aggregate(
    nactive=Count('pk', filter=Q(status='active')),
    ncancelled=Count('pk', filter=Q(status='cancelled')),
    ndraft=Count('pk', filter=Q(status='draft'))
)
```

This will return a dictionary:

```
{
    'nactive': 25,
    'ncancelled': 25,
    'ndraft': 13
}
```

items for which it can not find a `Model` will be returned as `None`.

Comment: Thanks it works. `items for which it can not find a Model will be returned as None.` - the status field is a charfield, not FK so it should always find a Model.

Comment: @Milano: what I mean is that if there are *no* models with `status='active'`, then `{ 'nactive': None}`, it is possible that for example all your `Model` records have `status='draft'`, such that no items are active/cancelled.